# Integrate a product of two functions

Tags: integration

so, here's the problem..

∫  x(e^x²) dx

i solved this by integrate (e^x²)

and i got (e^x²)/2x

x and 2x are cancelled out

so, 1/2(e^x²)

but, i got the problem on the another question..

∫x(e^x)dx

i tried by using the same method as i did before

but it didn't work, i asked my friend and he said just try using integration by parts.

```
  Could you explain why the first method doesn't work on the 2nd question?
```

in fact that both of the questions have the same form (product of two functions)

what makes them different?

Thankyou :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).